# Как улучшить генерацию массива четных чисел?

Tags: java, массивы, инспекция-кода

Просьба помочь улучшить код.
Вот описание задания:

> Напишите метод `evenArray`, который принимает целое число типа `int` и возвращает массив, заполненный четными числами от 1 до этого числа.
>
> Пример ввода: 8
> Пример вывода: [2,4,6,8]
>
> 1. Метод должен быть публичным.
> 2. Параметр должен иметь тип `int`.
> 3. Сигнатура метода должна быть: `evenArray(int number)`

Мой вариант решения:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(evenArray(8)));
}

public static int[] evenArray(int number) {
    int[] array = new int[number / 2];
    for (int i = 0, n = 2; i < array.length; n = n + 2, i++) {
        array[i] = n;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = (i + 1) * 2;
}
```

Число может быть отрицательным?

Comment: я так понимаю, что только положительные числа учитываются. Спасибо за помощь :)

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.printf(Arrays.toString(evenArray(10)));
}

public static int[] evenArray(int number) {
    return IntStream.iterate(2, i->i+2)
            .limit(number/2).toArray();
}
```

На выходе

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Comment: +1, есть еще [`iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntPredicate-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-), который включает в себя условие

Comment: я в потоках не силен, я просто гуглить умею. Занес первое, что загуглилось :)

Comment: OK. Если что, можно обойтись без `limit`: https://ideone.com/8UI1To

Comment: по производительности и по памяти это все равно скорее всего будет то же самое. По читабельности тоже примерно одно и то же. В чем тогда преимущество вашего варианта?

Comment: Чем меньше методов тем лучше :) Принципиальной разницы нет, дело вкуса.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ уже дан. Просто напомню что это можно сделать потоками:

```
public static int[] evenArray(int number) { 
     return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, number/2).map(x -> x*2).toArray();
}
```

Comment: Мысли сходятся :)

Comment: Спасибо за интересные решения :)

Comment: Плюсик  за красоту)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с использованием [`IntStream.filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#filter-java.util.function.IntPredicate-):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(evenArray(8))); // [2, 4, 6, 8]
}

public static int[] evenArray(int number) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, number).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).toArray();
}
```

В случае, если переданное число отрицательное, вернет пустой массив.

Answer (score 0):

Проходим полпути от единицы до переданного числа, пройденные числа умножаем на два:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(evenArray(8))); // [2, 4, 6, 8]
}

public static int[] evenArray(int number) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, number / 2).map(i -> i * 2).toArray();
}
```